# Avoiding duplicates in breadth-first search

Tags: algorithm, haskell, functional-programming

For educational purposes I've recently been implementing common algorithms in Haskell. Currently I'm stuck on Breadth-First Search. This is my implementation, with nodes being represented as just integers for simplicity:

```
import qualified Data.Map as M
import qualified Data.List as L

type Node = Int
type Graph = M.Map Node [Node]

-- Returns list of nodes adjacent to n in graph g
adjacent :: Node -> Graph -> [Node]
adjacent n g = M.findWithDefault [] n g

-- Returns graph g with all instances of n removed
rip :: Node -> Graph -> Graph
rip n g = M.delete n (M.map (L.delete n) g)

bfs :: Node -> Graph -> [Node]
bfs n g = [n] ++ _bfs [n] g

_bfs :: [Node] -> Graph -> [Node]
_bfs (n:ns) g =
    if not (M.null g) then
        let layer = adjacent n g in
            layer ++ _bfs (ns ++ layer) (rip n g)
    else n:ns
_bfs [] g = []
```

(There are other functions for actually constructing the graph, but I left them out for brevity's sake)

The result of calling `bfs` would be a correct breadth-first traversal of the graph, if not for the fact that some graphs produce duplicates, such as this one:

[image: The graph]

(The result of `bfs 1 g` for `g` = this graph is `[1,2,3,4,4,5,6,7,7,7]`)

My current solution boils down to changing the relevant line in `_bfs` to `L.nub $ layer ++ _bfs (ns ++ layer) (rip n g)`, but that seems incredibly hackish, and I'm not sure if it'll produce a correct breadth-first traversal. Aside from constantly checking `n:ns` for duplicates before inserting (which sounds horribly inefficient), I have no other ideas.

How can I rewrite `_bfs` (or more) so that it does not produce duplicates by definition?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use a set of visited nodes instead of `rip`.

First, `rip` takes linear time in the number of remaining edges, which makes the whole breadth-first traversal quadratic.

Second, the no-duplicates traversal is not practical with `rip`. Currently, duplicate nodes are added because the same nodes can be visited from multiple nodes of the current frontier of traversal. The revisits can't be simply pruned with `rip` because it removes the node from the graph altogether, but we still need the node in order to continue the traversal.

Here's an example with a visited set in a `State` monad (which is nice here, since we can build up the traversal frontier by frontier, and `filterM` from `Control.Monad` is handy for, well, filtering out visited nodes):

```
import qualified Data.IntMap.Strict as IM
import qualified Data.IntSet as IS

import Control.Monad
import Control.Monad.State.Strict

type Node = Int
type Graph = IM.IntMap [Node]

bfs :: Node -> Graph -> [Node]
bfs n g = evalState (go [n]) (IS.singleton n) where

    go :: [Node] -> State IS.IntSet [Node]
    go [] = return []
    go ns = do
        ns' <- flip filterM ((g IM.!) =<< ns) $ \n' -> do
            notVisited <- gets (IS.notMember n')
            when notVisited $ modify (IS.insert n')
            return notVisited
        (ns++) `fmap` go ns'

-- your example graph
graph :: Graph
graph = IM.fromList $ [
      (1, [2, 3])
    , (2, [1, 4])
    , (3, [1, 4])
    , (4, [2, 5, 3, 6])
    , (5, [4, 7])
    , (6, [4, 7])
    , (7, [5, 6])]

main = print $ bfs 1 graph -- [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
```

Here's is an implementation of the same algorithm without `State`, instead using `foldr` to pass along the updated visited set:

```
bfs' :: Node -> Graph -> [Node]
bfs' start graph = go [start] (IS.singleton start) where

    go :: [Node] -> IS.IntSet -> [Node]
    go [] _       = []
    go ns visited = ns ++ go ns' visited' where

        newNodes = [n' | n <- ns, n' <- graph IM.! n]

        step n (acc, visited) 
            | IS.member n visited = (acc, visited)
            | otherwise = (n:acc, IS.insert n visited) 

        (ns', visited') = foldr step ([], visited) newNodes
```

Comment: Monads are still pretty much beyond me. Regardless, thank you for your answer, I'll accept it eventually if a simpler one doesn't come along.

Comment: @MoreAxes: I added an implementation without monads, I hope it's more accessible.

Comment: It is, thank you. Do you know where I could find some resource about monads that explains them well? Neither the documentation nor the wiki seem to be that helpful here. Is it one of those things that just "click" when you've been thinking about them for long enough?

Comment: @MoreAxes: there are dozens and dozens of monad tutorials out there; see [this page](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Monad_tutorials_timeline) for a list. Also, trying to write lots of code with various monads is essential for understanding.

Comment: I didn't know that page existed. Again, thanks a ton.

Comment: @MoreAxes monads for a Haskell programmer are just *programs*. You construct a pure functional value that is a program; then it will run when the executable runs ("pure" monads can also run as part of your code). Since programs are native pure functional values, you can have regular Haskell functions that create (possibly non-pure) programs. You also can combine a program with a {program-creating function that will receive the value *produced* by the first program *when* it *will* run} into a new program. The meaning of "run", "produced" and "combine" is what defines a particular monad.

Answer (score 1):

You need to remember which nodes you have traversed so far and pass that information around. And use a data structure with efficient membership testing operation. A good candidate would be [`Set`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/containers-0.5.5.1/docs/Data-Set.html), or if you're using just `Int` for nodes then [`IntSet`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/containers-0.5.5.1/docs/Data-IntSet.html).

Comment: Wouldn't this be fairly inefficient as well, since you can't really easily have mutable state in Haskell? If this was C++, I'd just flip a boolean, but in Haskell I need to return the whole thing, over and over... Unless the compiler can optimize these things very well. I don't know enough (or anything, really) about the optimizations typically performed in functional languages.

Comment: @MoreAxes: Actually, just flipping bits in a mutable bitvector is pretty easy in Haskell too (see the ST monad and Data.Vector.Mutable), but in practice using `IntMap` and `IntSet` is even simpler and performant enough most of the time.

Comment: @MoreAxes In particular `IntSet` is implemented as a balanced tree whose leaves are 32-bit or 64-bit words used as bitmaps. So the structure is very efficient both in time and space, and all operations are just _O(log n)_.

Comment: @PetrPudlák So I would just keep an `IntSet` of the nodes I've visited, and before concatenating the new layer to the result I would filter out those elements that are in the `IntSet`?

Comment: @MoreAxes Even better, just completely skip visiting nodes that are in the set, when constructing another layer.

Comment: @MoreAxes correct, but do this node-by-node, not by-frontier (assuming there are no duplicate edges); or else first remove duplicates from the new frontier extension. Those duplicates might not yet be in the set of visited nodes.  @ PetrPudlák that's not better, that's worse, 'coz you run the risk of adding duplicates to the queue, from under two different freshly-visited nodes (as in OP's example).